# Unable to Send Outlook Email via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I can create an email and display it with my script, but for some reason it doesn't send and I receive the following error. Am I missing something, maybe there's a permissions issue?

```
Exception calling "Send" with "0" argument(s): "Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))"At C:\TEMP\Scripts\PowerShell\Outlook EMail Creation\TestEMailSend.ps1:27 char:5
+     $mail.Send()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

My code:

```
$global:UserReportsToEmail = "my.email@domain.com"
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.To = "$global:UserReportsToEmail"
$mail.cc = "EMAIL@domain.com"
$mail.Subject = "mySubject" 
$mail.HTMLBody = 
"<font color ='blue'><b>TESTING STUFFFF!</b></font><br>
Text on a new line $UserID"

$mail.Send()
$inspector = $mail.GetInspector
$inspector.Display()
```

Comment: I just tested your code and it works for me, which powershell version are you using?

Comment: I'm on version 4.

Answer (score 1):

According to a few of the Microsoft sites (e.g. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/80c66a08-66ee-4ab6-b629-6b1e70143eb0/operation-aborted-exception-from-hresult-0x80004004-eabort-outlook-appointment?forum=outlookdev ) this is due to 'object model guard'. A security feature to prevent automated programs from doing stuff like auto-emailing out viruses and stuff from the background.

You probably already worked this out. Posting this here so that others like myself can more quickly and easily understand why its not working.

Comment: Thank you for that redirection. However, do you happen to know how we can bypass it (specifically using PowerShell)?

Comment: No I don't. Most likely I was trying to do something similar, found the question, found my own answer and added it. For automated email I would just use a proper SMTP server and Send-MailMessage or similar.

Comment: Thank you. I found out that changing the required keys at the following location and **restarting Outlook** works:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\security`
Specifically, it was setting `promptoomsend` to 2 that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `Send-MailMessage` CmdLets : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx

then when i need more controls and dispose functionnality i use System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

```
    try
    {
        $emailCredentials = Import-Clixml "C:\testMail\credentials.clixml"
        $recipients = @("user@mail.com", "user2@mail.com", "user3@mail.com")
        $attachments = @("C:\testMail\file.txt", ""C:\testMail\file2.txt", "C:\testMail\file3.txt")

        # create mail and server objects
        $message = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        $smtp = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($buildInfoData.BuildReports.Mail.Server)

        # build message
        $recipients | % { $message.To.Add($_) }
        $message.Subject = $subject
        $message.From = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress($emailCredentials.UserName)
        $message.Body = $mailHtml
        $message.IsBodyHtml = $true
        $attachments | % { $message.Attachments.Add($(New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment $_)) }

        # build SMTP server
        $smtp = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(smtp.googlemail.com)
        $smtp.Port = 572
        $smtp.Credentials = [System.Net.ICredentialsByHost]$emailCredentials
        $smtp.EnableSsl = $true

        # send message
        $smtp.Send($message)

        Write-Host "Email message sent" 
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning "$($_.Exception | Select Message, Source, ErrorCode, InnerException, StackTrace | Format-List | Out-String)" 
    }
    finally
    {
        Write-Verbose "Disposing Smtp Object"
        $message.Dispose()
        $smtp.Dispose()
    }
```

Comment: This is good to know, but unfortunately it's not an option for me.

Comment: sometimes you don't have stmp server permission, but have access to Outlook

Comment: you can't user either send-mailmessage or .net smtp object ? why ?

Comment: SMTP access is restricted, but I can use Outlook.